# Redirect Struts Action Result to a New Tab based on Form Value

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

Our Struts Action class should redirect output to a **new tab** depending on a form value -- not always.

The standard suggestion is to add

```
<input type="button" onclick=openNewWindow('validate.do?param=myParam');"
```

JS:

```
openNewWindow: function(url) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

But this won't work for us. We should not automatically open a new tab in every case; it depends on a certain form value, which we have to check on the server-side in the Action class.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use Javascript, form element has target attribute:

```
<s:form target="${param.paramAttr eq 'myParam' ? '_blank' : '' }" action="validate.do"
  method="post" 
>
..
</s:form>
```